# Jest - Test is successful even though it should not be

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I've simplified my scripts to let you easily understand what's going on. I have a test that waits for an object to be ready before checking whether an array contains a value.

```
const list = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
describe('check array', (done) => {
  it('should not contain D', () => {
    const monitor = new Monitor();

    monitor.ready().then(() => {
      expect(list.indexOf('D')).toEqual(1);

      done();
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see, `D` is not an element of `list` (so `indexOf` should return -1), but this test still passes. I've tried both `toEqual` and `toBe` with no luck. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the fact that I'm waiting for the Promise to resolve first? Thanks!

Comment: `done` is the argument to `it`, not `describe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `await` your `monitor.ready()`, something like this:

```js
const list = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

describe('check array', (done) => {
  // made function async
  it('should not contain D', async () => {
    const monitor = new Monitor();

    // wait until this call finished before continuing
    await monitor.ready();
    
    expect(list.indexOf('D')).toEqual(1);

    // not sure where this is from or what it's for
    // I assume it's defined somewhere else in your code
    done(); 
  });
});
```

Without doing the `async`/`await`, the test finished without a failed assertion or an error which Jest interprets as a passing test because the code in the `.then(() => {...})` doesn't run until AFTER the test has been marked successful

Comment: `done` is the _other_ way to test async functionality in Jest: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks

Comment: Ahh, cool, TIL. Looks like the issue there then is that `done` was defined in the `describe` and not in the `it`

Comment: Pretty sure I gave it a try with `done` in `it`, but I'm gonna check against. Thanks for the feedback!